# Can I post answer based on OP's self-answer post?

Tags: support, self-answer

I'm fairly sure this has been discussed here in the past. The OP answered their own question with a code which has a few issues (two are serious, but not related to the asked topic, they are general). I didn't know what to do, hence I've suggested edit and for the OP added comment that contains link to that review, because such suggestions should be declined (which correctly happened).

What should I do in this case?

Should I post my own answer based on the OP's answer with fixed issues (which are not specific to the asked topic)?

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45122472/8041231) & [My code review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16729191)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can post an answer that's based on the work of another answer.  Just be sure that you cite the answer that yours is based off of, and do your best to indicate what is your original work and what content is someone else's.

Comment: And what to do with the original asnwer? It has two, quite serious issues (not directly related to the topic, it's a wrong construct). Shall I downvote?

Comment: @Victoria If you think that the answer isn't helpful as a result of those problems, yes.  If you feel that the problems don't make the answer unhelpful as a whole, then no.

Comment: Hmm, that's the point. It is helpful. It shows what to do, but it has two issues I pointed out in the comment (maybe it's just a typo). And as the question is formulated, it can spread all over the world :)

Comment: Resolved with the OP. Thank you for the support!